# does swagger support JWT authentication?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, swagger, drf-yasg

How can I add JWT as an authentication for Swagger?
Here is my Swagger Settings:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "SECURITY_DEFINITIONS": {
        "JWT": {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "description": "JWT authorization",
            "type": "http",
            "scheme": "bearer",
            "bearerFormat": "JWT",
            "in": "header",
        }
    },
    "USE_SESSION_AUTH": False,
}
```

I get

> Unknown security definition type http

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        "Auth Token eg [Bearer {JWT}]": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "Authorization",
            "in": "header"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Mahdi, this indeed looks like a good idea but unfortunely it did not work :( I still have to write Bearer {JWT}

Comment: Anyways I started new question because this is different then the intended question